# cifar10 как выбрать определенные классы для класификации?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensorflow

Как класифицировать только определенные классы из 10 существующих в библиотке Cifar10?

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
```

Понимаю, что это обрабатывает все 10 существующих классов. А как переписать на выбранные, понятия не имею. Может кто-то помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

---

```
In [67]: mask_train = np.in1d(y_train, [1,2,3,4])

In [68]: y_train[mask_train]
Out[68]:
array([[4],
       [1],
       [1],
       ...,
       [2],
       [1],
       [1]], dtype=uint8)

In [69]: mask_test = np.in1d(y_test, [8,9])

In [70]: y_test[mask_test]
Out[70]:
array([[8],
       [8],
       [9],
       ...,
       [8],
       [8],
       [8]])
```

При помощи `mask_train` можно выбрать соответствующие записи из `x_train` и также использовать `mask_test`  для `x_test`